# Attempting to List Product Categories along with the price range of their products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to create a page where I display a list of categories and the price range of the products within those categories.

E.g

**Headwear – £30-£150**

**Shoes – £35-£300**

Where "Headwear" is the Product Category Name, "£30" is the lowest price of a product within that category and "£150" is the highest.

So far I have used the following code to list the categories, but not sure how to check for products within each and get the prices etc.

```
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false ;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);
 
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
 
if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '
 
<ul>';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '
 
<li>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>
 
 
';
}
```

I'm fairly inexperienced in Woocommerce so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of products by product category slug with the following snippet (source: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-get-return-all-product-ids/):

```
   $all_ids = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'fields' => 'ids',
      'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'your_product_cat',
            'operator' => 'IN',
         )
      ),
   ));
```

So, for each category, you can loop through products and find the least and most expensive:

```
$min = PHP_FLOAT_MAX;
$max = 0.00;
foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
   $product = wc_get_product( $id );
   $min = $product->get_price() < $min ? $product->get_price() : $min;
   $max = $product->get_price() > $max ? $product->get_price() : $max;
}
```

All together with your code now:

```
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);   
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
if ( ! empty( $product_categories ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $product_categories as $key => $category ) {
        $all_ids = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => $category->slug,
                  'operator' => 'IN',
               )
            ),
        ));
        $min = PHP_FLOAT_MAX;
        $max = 0.00;
        foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
           $min = wc_format_decimal( $product->get_price() ) < $min ? wc_format_decimal( $product->get_price() ) : $min;
           $max = wc_format_decimal( $product->get_price() ) > $max ? wc_format_decimal( $product->get_price() ) : $max;
        }
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $category ) . '">';
        echo $category->name . ' - ' . wc_price( $min ) . '-' . wc_price( $max );
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```